# Golang generics parameter to pass a type implemeting an interface

Tags: go, generics

In the following [golang](/questions/tagged/golang) snippet ([Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ITQ_H6pmVeQ))
how to specify that the `T` type implements the `json.Unmarshaler` interface in order to call `helper[MyStruct](jsonTxt)`?

```golang
package main

import "encoding/json"

func main() {
    jsonTxt := []byte(`{"val":"fake"}`)

    // I want to call my helper function like this:
    helper[MyStruct](jsonTxt) // build error: MyStruct does not implement json.Unmarshaler (UnmarshalJSON method has pointer receiver)
    // else like that:
    helper[*MyStruct](jsonTxt) // runtime panic: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
}

// Question: How to say T is a type implementing the json.Unmarshaler interface?
func helper[T json.Unmarshaler](jsonTxt []byte) {
    var s T
    s.UnmarshalJSON(jsonTxt)
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Val string
}

// implements json.Unmarshaler
func (m *MyStruct) UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error {
    m.Val = "fake"
    return nil
}
```

I know a valid workaround is to instantiate `MyStruct` as a function argument: ([Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/8FS1jtcGpLk))

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    jsonTxt := []byte(`{"val":"fake"}`)
    helper(&MyStruct{}, jsonTxt)
}

func helper[T json.Unmarshaler](s T, jsonTxt []byte) {
    s.UnmarshalJSON(jsonTxt)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", s)
    // Output: &{Val:fake}
}

[...]
```

But I would prefer to avoid the `&MyStruct{}` trick. Is it possible to replace the `[T json.Unmarshaler]` by something smarter? I have attempted things like the following but without success:

```golang
func helper[*T U, U json.Unmarshaler](jsonTxt []byte) {
    var s T
    s.UnmarshalJSON(jsonTxt)
}
```

Note: That `helper()` function is to reduce code duplication in my JSON serializers benchmark: the function does not need to return something.

Comment: Why generics? `func helper(jum json.Unmarshaler, src []byte)` No need for generics here.

Comment: Thank you @Volker You are right. But I want to move most of the duplicated code in `helper()`, thus I want to instantiate the `MyStruct` variable in `helper()`, for example by writing something like `var s T`. I hope this comment clarifies what I want to do. Else, please propose your idea as a snippet on https://go.dev/play ;-)

Comment: You shouldn't call `s.UnmarshalJSON()` yourself. Call `json.Unmarshal()` which will call it. You may pass `&s` to it, and it will be created when needed. See https://go.dev/play/p/6T6_P4DFMNV

Comment: Yes @icza but I am benching JSON encoders/decoders: what you propose is the kind of indirect call I would like to measure: is it a negligible penalty? Thank you very much for the Go Playground link ;-D For your information, the interface I am currently benching is `easyjson.MarshalerUnmarshaler`.